# Adding correlation and p-value to a plotly chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, font-style

I use ggplot2 to create a point plot and then I add the correlation coefficient to that chart. Next, I use plotly to see info about each data point. However, there is a mistake in font style in the plot as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDkYO.png).

I need R = 0.87 and P = 2.2e-16, not "italic(R)" or "italic(P)", while keeping mapping part in stat_cor. I guess, plotly cannot understand `italic(p)` part as a code. The solution should not fix that adding a text manually, I need the calculation of "R" and "P".

Here is the code:

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris) +
      geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) +
      stat_cor(mapping = aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length))
p2 <- ggplotly(p1)
p2
```

Comment: Would using ['ggiraph'](https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/) instead of 'plotly' be an option for you? It works far better with 'ggplot' and has the same interactive features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add anotations to the plotly chart - any sort of R functions and html code are going to work as part of the text.

### Plotly only solution

A possible solution is using plotly directly, not using ggplot then converting.

The code would be:

```
p2 <- plot_ly(data = iris, x=~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length) |>   #base R pipe operator
  add_annotations(
  xref = "paper", yref = "paper",
  x = 0.1, y = 0.9, 
  text = paste0("<i>R</i> = ", round(cor(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length),2), "<br>",
            "<i>P</i> = ", formatC(cor.test(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)$p.value,
                                       format="e", digits=2)),
  showarrow = F,   # Does not show an arrow indicating the text position
  align = "left")  #align the text left
p2
```

- "paper" defines how x and y applies (relative to the axis (paper) or on specific value)
- x = 0.1, y = 0.9 says that the text will be placed at the 10% of the x-axis and 90% of the y-axis.
- text is the text itself. I am using basic functions to calculate R and p-value, and html symbols to edit the text.

### Alternative using ggplotly

As you prefer to use ggplotly, the exact same annotation can be used on it. In this case, the code is:

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length))
p2 <- ggplotly(p1) |>
      add_annotations(
        xref = "paper", yref = "paper",
        x = 0.01, y = 0.95, 
        text = paste0("<i>R</i> = ", round(cor(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length),2),
                      "<br>",
                      "<i>P</i> = ", formatC(cor.test(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)$p.value,
                                            format="e", digits=2)),
      showarrow = F,   # Does not show an arrow indicating the text position
      align = "left")  #align the text left
p2
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It's working, but it is difficult to add facet in plotly for shiny app.

Comment: Got it, I added a solution using ggplotly, then. Hope it works for you. If you think it is a good solution, please accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue when creating a `ggplot()` then putting it into `ggplotly()`.

I solved it by using the argument `stat_cor(output.type="text")`.